# Grouped UITableView with fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I had a grouped `tableView` with 1 section, cell's content was supplied by `fetchedResultsController`. Now I need to modify this tableview a little. I need to add one UITableviewCell with it's own custom content (independent from `fetchedResultsController`) as single only for first section. Section two must be same as previous version of this `tableView` was. So just adding one cell in one section before all existing content. Related methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}
```

but I am having `SIGABRT` here and `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`. `fetchedResultsController` retrives data fine, and it is not empty, so what is wrong here?

Comment: What is the code in tableview cellforat indexpath??

Comment: Try to NSLog(@"numb of sections=%i",[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that section #1 in the table view is section #0 for the 
fetched results controller. 
So you have to adjust the section number in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
         NSInteger frcSection = section - 1;
         id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:frcSection];
         return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}
```

Note that similar adjustments are necessary

- in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,
- in the fetched results controller delegate methods

to map between the FRC index path and its corresponding table view index path.

I would write your first method as

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1 + [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

so that it works even if the FRC has no sections or more than 1 section.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Also I need to update -cellForRowAtIndexPath: and every other places where I am using FRC.